# If you authorize the same iOS app on multiple devices, is the same oAuth token returned?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I have a scenario where a user will use the same Facebook account on multiple devices with our app.  As part of the FB authorization, we ask for "extended data permissions" which makes teh FB oauth token long lived.

I'm trying to figure out whether our server needs to specifically support multiple devices or whether Facebook will return the same oAuth token to all the devices for the same FB account.

If it does, then it means that support 1 or N devices should be the same for me.
If not, then it means I have to track N oauth tokens on our server and differentiate between device IDs (UDIDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook generates one token per app per user, *if* you request offline_access when you authenticate your app (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). So, it doesn't matter on which device the user logs in, Facebook will give you the same token every time.